# Concurrent requests with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise, axios

In a React app I need to post data from a form. The post creates a new dashboard object. Once that's done, I need to immediately update a select dropdown in the component to include the newly added dashboard name. The [axios documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)  says it should be done like so:

```
function getUserAccount() {
   return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
   return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
.then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
// Both requests are now complete
}));
```

So this is what I've done:

```
class DashboardForm extends Component {

saveDashboard() {
    var siteId = this.state.siteId;
    var self= this;
    return axios.post('/path/to/save/dashboard' + siteId + '/dashboards', {
        slug: this.refs.dashboardUrl.value,
        name: this.refs.dashboardName.value,
    }).then(function (response) {
        self.setState({
            dashboardId: response.data.dashboardId,
            dashboardName: response.data.dashboardName,
            submitMessage: (<p>Successfully Created</p>)
        });
        self.setUrl(siteId, response.data.dashboardId);

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        self.setState({
            submitMessage: (<p>Failed</p>)
        });
    });
}

getAllDashboards(){
    var self = this;
    self.setState({siteId: this.props.selectedSiteID});
    var getDashboardsPath = "path/to/get/dashboards/" + self.props.selectedSiteID + "/dashboards";

    axios(getDashboardsPath, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'GET',
        cache: 'no-cache'
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data.dashboards;
    }).then(function (arrDashboards) {   //populate options for the select
        var options = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrDashboards.length; i++) {
            var option = arrDashboards[i];
            options.push(
                (<option className="dashboardOptions" key={option.dashboardId} value={option.slug}>{option.name}</option>)
            );
        }
        self.setState({
            options: options
        });
    });
}

saveAndRepopulate() {
    axios.all([saveDashboard(), getAllDashboards()])
        .then(axios.spread(function (savedDashboard, listOfDashboards) {
            // Both requests are now complete
        }));
     }

}
```

The saveAndRepopulate is called when the form submits.

The problem is that I get the following errors:

```
error    'saveDashboard' is not defined             no-undef
error    'getAllDashboards' is not defined          no-undef
```

I've tried doing

```
function saveDashboard() {
```

but then I get

Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ( (175:13)

```
  | 
  |     function saveDashboard() {
  |              ^
```

How do I call these two functions? Also, am I going to need to change the promise (.then) from the individual calls to the saveAndPopulate?

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: try `axios.all([this.saveDashboard(), ...` etc

Comment: Uhhh.  Yep that was it. Can't believe I didn't try that.  Thanks. Make it an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if this is the right approach.  It looks to me like when you use axios.all() the order of execution of the calls is not guaranteed. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Since order matters, perform the two operations sequentially - `return this.saveDashboard().then(this.getAllDashboards).then(function() {...});`

Answer (score 0):

First, as @Jaromanda X pointed out, you should call your inside components functions with `this`, and you need to bind these functions to `this`. There are multiple ways to do that, one of then is to bind it inside the component constructor like:

`this.saveDashboard = this.saveDashboard.bind(this)`

Other good thing to do is to return the axios call inside the `saveDashboard()` and `getAllDashboards()`